# Mysql join query - phpmyadmin error is 'not unique table alias'

Tags: mysql

Guys was looking for a little help. I was trying to run this query in php myadmin. Needing to update a temp table with 4 sets of data..3 sets from one table..and 1 from another table, while joining 3 tables. The error comes back after my second JOIN that I do not have a unique table alias. I'm not sure how to fix that. Can anyone see where the query is going wrong? Thanks.

```
INSERT INTO jos_jxgallery_assign_ratings_temp( image_id, pscore, hits, contest_id )
SELECT jos_jxgallery_images.image_id, jos_jxgallery_images.pscore, jos_jxgallery_images.hits, jos_jxgallery_contests.contest_id
    FROM jos_jxgallery_images, jos_jxgallery_contests
    INNER JOIN jos_jxgallery_contest_image_map ON jos_jxgallery_images.image_id = jos_jxgallery_contest_image_map.image_id
    INNER JOIN jos_jxgallery_contests ON jos_jxgallery_contest_image_map.contest_id = jos_jxgallery_contests.contest_id
    WHERE jos_jxgallery_contests.published =1
    AND jos_jxgallery_images.published =1
    ORDER BY jos_jxgallery_images.pscore DESC , jos_jxgallery_images.hits DESC
    LIMIT 25

    MySQL said: Documentation
        #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'jos_jxgallery_contests'
```

Now when I change the query to this...I get another error listed below the query. Any ideas?

```
 INSERT INTO jos_jxgallery_assign_ratings_temp( image_id, pscore, hits, contest_id )
SELECT jos_jxgallery_images.image_id, jos_jxgallery_images.pscore, jos_jxgallery_images.hits, jos_jxgallery_contests.contest_id
FROM jos_jxgallery_images, jos_jxgallery_contests
INNER JOIN jos_jxgallery_contest_image_map ON jos_jxgallery_images.image_id = jos_jxgallery_contest_image_map.image_id
INNER JOIN jos_jxgallery_contests AS con ON jos_jxgallery_contest_image_map.contest_id = con.contest_id
WHERE con.published =1
AND jos_jxgallery_images.published =1
ORDER BY jos_jxgallery_images.pscore DESC , jos_jxgallery_images.hits DESC
LIMIT 25

MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'jos_jxgallery_images.image_id' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an `AS` to the second join so:
`INNER JOIN jos_jxgallery_contests as myTableTwo ON`

You can then refence columns from that join explicitly with the myTableTwo.column name

Also you can just put the second `INNER JOIN` in you `WHERE` clause I believe so  `AND jos_jxgallery_contest_image_map.contest_id = jos_jxgallery_contests.contest_id`

Comment: I tried what you were saying and updated my question above.

Comment: Show the table structure. Usually MySQL is right in its error messages. So I suspect there really is no column image_id.

Comment: There's quite definitely an image_id column in the jos_jxgallery_images table and also an image_id column in the jos_jx_gallery_image_map table...100 percent. Maybe I'm supposed to alias the images table or something?

Answer (score 0):

You use the jos_jxgallery_contests in FROM and INNER JOIN. In INNER JOIN you make a ambiguous connection. Why you try to do that?